# Is it possible to allow a background process to continuously output to terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal, c, background-process, cal

Here's a use-case to clarify my question. Say I have a calendar program that is set to run in `~/.bashrc`, and it ensures the streaming output overwrites the same block of lines.

Is it possible to have the streaming output display in the terminal from the background process without clobbering new input? I already looked at [Displaying stdout of a background process in specific location of the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14169/152446), but the asker requires outputting new lines at termination, which I don't need to do.

Here's a screenshot of the program output, which currently runs in the foreground and terminates after outputting the formatted text once:
[image: Terminal after program output]

I just want that formatted text to continually replace itself while allowing foreground processes to function as normal. A solution in Bash, C, and / or C++ using something like `zsh` or ANSI escape sequences would be perfect for me.

For reference, here's the current C code I'm using, but if it's easier for you, you could just formulate a solution that uses `cal` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

const char months[12][10] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
const char weekDays[7][10] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

void printCalendar(void);
int getWeekDay(int, int, int, int, int);
int getMaxDay(int, int);
void getDate(int *, int *, int *, int *, int *, int *, int *);
void formatTime(char *, int, int, int);

int main(void) {
  printCalendar();

  return 0;
}

void printCalendar(void) {
  int second, minute, hour, day, month, year, weekDay, maxDay, col, x = 0, i;
  char str[12];

  getDate(&second, &minute, &hour, &day, &month, &year, &weekDay);
  formatTime(str, hour, minute, second);
  maxDay = getMaxDay(month, year);

  printf("\e[3J");

  printf("%s %s\n", weekDays[weekDay], str);
  printf("%s %d, %d\n\n ", months[month], day, year);

  printf("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat\n ");

  for (i = 1; i <= maxDay; i++) {
    col = getWeekDay(i, month, year, day, weekDay);

    if (x > col) {
      x = 0;
      printf("\n ");
    }

    while (x < col) {
      x++;
      printf("    ");
    }

    x++;

    if (i == day) {
      if (i < 10) {
        printf(" ");
      }

      printf(" \e[7m%d\e[0m ", i);
    } else {
      printf("%3d ", i);
    }
  }

  printf("\n\n");
}

int getWeekDay(int day, int month, int year, int rmday, int rwday) {
  return (day - rmday + rwday + 35) % 7;
}

int getMaxDay(int month, int year) {
  switch (month) {
    case 3: // April
    case 5: // June
    case 8: // September
    case 10:// November
      return 30;
    case 1: // February
      if ((year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0) || year % 4 != 0) {
        return 28; // Not leap year
      }

      return 29; // Leap year
    default:
      return 31; // Remaining months
  }
}

void getDate(int *second, int *minute, int *hour, int *day, int *month, int *year, int *weekDay) {
  time_t now;
  struct tm *date;

  time(&now);
  date = localtime(&now);

  *second = (date -> tm_sec);
  *minute = (date -> tm_min);
  *hour = (date -> tm_hour);
  *day = (date -> tm_mday);
  *month = (date -> tm_mon);
  *year = (date -> tm_year) + 1900;
  *weekDay = (date -> tm_wday);
}

void formatTime(char *str, int hour, int minute, int second) {
  sprintf(str, "%02d:%02d:%02d %s", (hour % 12) ? (hour % 12) : 12, minute, second, hour / 12 ? "PM" : "AM");
  str[11] = '\0';
}
```

And the code in `~/.bashrc` is just:

```
clear && ~/Documents/C/Calendar/calendar
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Thoughts: `screen` (or probably `tmux`) with a split, where the upper section is just large enough for the command output. If you are okay with it updating only after pressing Return, then `$PROMPT_COMMAND` is sufficient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend GNU `screen` for this. First, start up a new `screen` instance:

```
$ screen
```

Then make a split with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. You can resize the top portion with the `resize` command. I found a height of 9 to be reasonable for `cal`:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> `:resize 9`

Then use any command that constantly produces output. I don't use `watch` or even have it on many systems, but

```
while true; do cal; sleep 3; done
```

works just as well.

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> moves you to the other (bottom) part of the split. Finally, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> opens a new shell in which you can run commands without interference from the other portion of the split.

---

If you want this to occur automatically, you can use `.screenrc`:

```
screen /bin/sh -c 'while true; do cal; sleep 3; done'
split
resize 9
focus
screen
```

See `screen(1)` for a full description of commands, and possible inspiration for alternative configurations.

Comment: I love this answer! Is there a way to do the keystrokes programmatically though? This would be perfect

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I've edited my answer to accommodate that. I fully `expect` someone to recommend something else though

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you for your quick response!

Comment: I ended up adding `if ! screen -list | grep -q "on"; then clear && screen; fi` to the `~/.bashrc` and `statup_message off; defshell -bash` to the `~/.screenrc` so the bottom split screen would have the normal bash interface, I wish I could upvote this again!

Comment: @Fox if someone does, just `send` them away

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes. It is possible to have a background running application that outputs something on `stdout`:

`ping 8.8.8.8 &> /dev/stdout &`

So:

- `&>` send `stdout` and `stderr` to `stdout`,
- `&` at the end makes `ping` working in background.

But, as far as I understand your use-case properly, the better idea will be to have `watch` [[1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/watch.htm)] application in foreground.
It runs periodically a command that is specified as an argument and presents its execution results.

Comment: The first portion of this will interfere with (hinder the viewing of) foreground tasks, and the second portion (`watch`) prevents any other command from being run